# Tensorflow target column always returns 1

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a classification problem with Tensorflow and I'm new to this. I want to see two targets (1 and 0) after all. I'm asking because I don't know, is it normal for the whole target column to be 1 as below? Thank you.

```
df['target'] = np.where(df['Class']== 2, 0, 1)

df = df.drop(columns=['Class'])
```

then when I run the command line below, the target column shows exactly 1.

```
print(df.head(50))
```

Comment: So when the condition is met you want the values to be changed to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the last parameter to the array you are making the comparisons on.

This will replace the values of `2` with `1` in `df["Class"]`

```
df['target'] = np.where(df['Class']== 2, 1, df['Class'])
```

Comment: Thank you. if there are more than one label value in the same column, How do I edit it?